# Cannot insert data when JpaTransactionManager configuration is added

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I added JpaTransactionManager into my application but for some reason INSERT queries are not executed at all. I use this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/app
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Insert code:

```
Service
@Qualifier("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public <S extends Users> S save(S entity) {
        try {

            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!! received entityManager.persist(entity);");

            entityManager.persist(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();             
        }
        return entity;
    }
    ...
}
```

Do you know am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to put EntityManager within persistence context, change:

```
@Autowired  
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

To

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```